# How to build libdevmapper static libraries?

Tags: c, linux, docker

I want to build docker source in centos 7, it use go and c++ , and it depend lib lvm (libdevmapper), and my question is: How to build libdevmapper static libraries?

when i compile it with configure flags :
[test@localhost lvm2]$ ./configure --enable-static_link --disable-selinux

and `make && make install`

```
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/test/modi-source/thirdSoftware/lvm2/tools'
gcc -O2  -fPIC -O2  -L../libdm -L../lib -L../libdaemon/client -static -L../libdm/ioctl -o lvm.static \
      command.o dumpconfig.o formats.o lvchange.o lvconvert.o lvconvert_poll.o lvcreate.o lvdisplay.o lvextend.o lvmcmdline.o lvmdiskscan.o lvreduce.o lvremove.o lvrename.o lvresize.o lvscan.o polldaemon.o pvchange.o pvck.o pvcreate.o pvdisplay.o pvmove.o pvmove_poll.o pvremove.o pvresize.o pvscan.o reporter.o segtypes.o tags.o toollib.o vgcfgbackup.o vgcfgrestore.o vgchange.o vgck.o vgcreate.o vgconvert.o vgdisplay.o vgexport.o vgextend.o vgimport.o vgmerge.o vgmknodes.o lvpoll.o vgimportclone.o vgreduce.o vgremove.o vgrename.o vgscan.o vgsplit.o  lvm-static.o -llvm-internal -ldaemonclient  -ldl  -ldevmapper    -lrt 
../lib/liblvm-internal.a(sharedlib.o): In function `load_shared_library':
sharedlib.c:(.text+0x131): warning: Using 'dlopen' in statically linked applications requires at runtime the shared libraries from the glibc version used for linking
../libdm/ioctl/libdevmapper.a(libdm-string.o): In function `dm_size_to_string':
libdm-string.c:(.text+0x11d0): undefined reference to `nearbyint'
libdm-string.c:(.text+0x11e5): undefined reference to `floor'
../libdm/ioctl/libdevmapper.a(pool.o): In function `dm_pool_create':
pool.c:(.text+0x15c): undefined reference to `pthread_mutex_lock'
pool.c:(.text+0x177): undefined reference to `pthread_mutex_unlock'
../libdm/ioctl/libdevmapper.a(pool.o): In function `dm_pool_destroy':
pool.c:(.text+0x1f9): undefined reference to `pthread_mutex_lock'
pool.c:(.text+0x20d): undefined reference to `pthread_mutex_unlock'
../libdm/ioctl/libdevmapper.a(pool.o): In function `dm_pools_check_leaks':
pool.c:(.text+0x640): undefined reference to `pthread_mutex_lock'
pool.c:(.text+0x6d5): undefined reference to `pthread_mutex_unlock'
pool.c:(.text+0x720): undefined reference to `pthread_mutex_unlock'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5/libgcc_eh.a(unwind-dw2-fde-dip.o): In function `__register_frame_info_bases':
```

can any one who build libdevmapper static ok ? wuwuwuuwuw......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fix it ,when the DM version is >97 . and the glibc will be  updated, so , all the lib will be commpiled in static lib file( exp. libdevmapper.a use libudev.a).